# Hasan vs Hasan Sahih

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-ar-rijal, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith

What is the difference between Hassan and Hassan Sahih Hadith?
I have seen this many times wheb I read the Books like Abu-Dawood or Ibne Maja that Albani said Hassan or Hassan Sahih about the hadith.
What's the difference?
And how Albani and other Muhaditheen do this grading?

Comment: Hassan sahih is a term that was used by imam at-Tirmidhi. The terminology of hadith is mainly a subjective matter, when it comes to earlier scholars. As ibn Salah was the first trying to define a unified terminology.

Comment: So in recent years, how people like Albani and Zubair Ali Zai do the grading of Hadith?

Comment: Based on earlier views and the qualifications of narrators I'd assume in fact there's a post asking about the methodology of al-Albani (see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/7095/13438)).

Comment: Can you share that please?